# Where should I put my new Bolt CMS theme to allow it to be committed?

Tags: php, symfony, bolt-cms

I'm following this tutorial on creating a Bolt CMS theme ...

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/courses/bolt-cms-theme-development/lessons/basic-theme-setup-and-intro-to-twig

... but I'm running into a problem: The tutorial tells me to create a new subdirectory inside of the `/theme` directory.

But this `/theme` directory is omitted from version control, along with all subdirectories!

I would like to treat my Bolt project as a monorepo, including my new custom theme.

**Is there another place I can put my theme, such that I can store it in my monorepo?** I really don't want to create a new repo just for a theme that's specific to my project.

Another option would be to change the `.gitignore` file that composer puts into place when I create a new Bolt project. I'll be happy to do that if there's not a better way, but I want to make sure I'm doing things the "right" way if possible.

Comment: Your theme directory probably shouldn't be included in .gitignore at all. I don't see it in the [master .gitignore](https://github.com/bolt/project/blob/master/.gitignore) anyway

Comment: Hi Aynber! Thanks for commenting. The `theme` folder is excluded via the `/public/.gitignore` file that composer puts in place. I could easily make this exclusion more specific by modifying that `.gitignore` file, of course, but I want to give a few people a chance to comment first in order to make sure I'm not being too kludgy :-)

Comment: (It's also possible that this `.gitignore` exclusion was put in place by the `bolt:copy-themes` command, which I ran after creating the project.)